# Merge 2 Json file in PHP

Tags: php, json, merge, array-merge

i want to merge some json file and display them after using a foreach function.

```
$urls = array( 'url_1','url_2', 'url_3', 'url_4', 'url_5');
$jobs = [];
foreach ($urls as $url){
$json = json_decode(get_content($url), true);
$jobs[] = $json;
}
$retour = json_encode($jobs);
foreach($retour as $job) {
 echo $job;
}
```

But nothing appear on my screen. And i have no error too.

When i do `echo $retour;` i have something like `[[{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}]]` instead of `[{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}]`.

How to solve this ?

Comment: Is array $url contain variables(url1,url2,...) as json?

Comment: `$retour` is a json string, you call `foreach` on a string

Comment: what get_content function does? Maybe you wanted to use `file_get_contents` ?

Comment: Yes it's `file_get_contents`

Comment: @KrisRoofe what is the right thing to do ?

Comment: @GyandeepSharma no just simple https urls that retour json array

Comment: so what are you decoding them.?

Comment: @GyandeepSharma yes something like that. I want to display just one url, it works perfectly. And this the code i use for :

Comment: Sorry, I want to ask - Why are you decoding them...?

Comment: `$jobs=json_decode(get_content("https://www.example.com"), true); foreach($jobs as $job) { echo $job;}`

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve with `$retour` as `[{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}]`
OR What you want as final output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the following and it seems to work as you want

```
<?php
 $urls = array( 'url_1','url_2');
 $jobs = [];
 foreach ($urls as $url){
   $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
   array_push($jobs, $json);
 }

 $unique = array();
 foreach ($jobs as $piece) {
    $unique = array_merge($unique, $piece);
 }
 $retour = json_encode($unique);
 print_r($retour); //it gives merged json :: {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":"value4"}
 $test[] = $retour;
 print_r($test); //to get it as array :: ([0] => {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":"value4"})
?>
```

I have created url_1 and url_2 as json file as follow

```
{
  "key1": "value1", 
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

and

```
{
  "key3": "value3",
  "key4": "value4"
}
```